# Scala: Chain flatmap vs nested flatmap

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I wonder in Scala, is there any difference/preference between these 2 pieces of code.

```
// common code
  case class Person(maybeAddress: Option[Address])
  case class Address(maybeZipCode: Option[String])
```

chained flatmap:

```
  maybePerson
    .flatMap(person => person.maybeAddress)
    .flatMap(address => address.maybeZipCode)
```

nested flatmap:

```
  maybePerson
    .flatMap(person => person.maybeAddress.flatMap(address => address.maybeZipCode))
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `Monad` laws state that both should produce the same result. - Thus pick the option you prefer or look into the `for` syntax.

Comment: No diff. 1st one is probably easier to read and refactor in this specific case. But it might be the opposite in other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example provided there is no much other difference than the style.

If we look at the **scaladoc** of [Option.flatmap](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/e46dd02d712871bc2e11811757b379f2ef8f7f02/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L282)

> ```scala
>   /** Returns the result of applying $f to this $option's value if
>    * this $option is nonempty.
>    *
>    * This is equivalent to:
>    * {{{
>    * option match {
>    *   case Some(x) => f(x)
>    *   case None    => None
>    * }
>    * }}}
>    */
>   @inline final def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] =
>     if (isEmpty) None else f(this.get)
> ```

if we rewrite each example of your question following the **pattern matching** showed in the **scaladoc**, for the first case it would be

```scala
// from
maybePerson
    .flatMap(person => person.maybeAddress)
    .flatMap(address => address.maybeZipCode)

// to
maybePerson match {
  case Some(person) => person.maybeAddress
  case None         => None
} match { // this match will always be applied
  case Some(address) => address.maybeZipCode
  case None          => None
}
```

for the second one would be

```scala
// from
maybePerson
    .flatMap(person => 
      person.maybeAddress
        .flatMap(address => 
          address.maybeZipCode
        )
    )

// to
maybePerson match {
  case Some(person) => 
        // this match will be applied only if maybePerson is Some
        person.maybeAddress match {
          case Some(address) => address.maybeZipCode
          case None          => None
        }
  case None => None
}
```

As I detailed before, in the example we are analyzing there is no much difference beside the style.

Maybe in a more complex scenario, you would have values that must be computed, some of them could be expensive to process or produce a side effect that you should rollback if something fails.

---

That being said, from my side I prefer to use for comprehensions

```scala
for {
  person  <- maybePerson
  address <- person.maybeAddress
  zipCode <- address.maybeZipCode
} yield zipCode
```

It's a more vertical style and avoids having nested blocks of code, unless you extract the anonymous functions to methods or functions declared in variables like this

```scala
def personToAddress(person: Person): Option[Address] =
  person.maybeAddress

def addressToZipCode(address: Address): Option[String] =
  address.maybeZipCode

// first case
maybePerson
    .flatMap(mapToAddress)
    .flatMap(mapToZipCode)

// second case
def addressToZipCode(address: Address) =
  address.maybeZipCode

def personToZipCode(person: Person) =
  person
    .maybeAddress
    .flatMap(addressToZipCode)

maybePerson
  .flatMap(personToZipCode)
```